# How to copy data from One database to another database on two different machines having live IP's?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

- Machine A: live IP 110.36.228.157 / Installed SQL Server 2014, have a database PCLS2018
- Machine B: live IP 110.36.228.156 / Installed SQL Server 2014, also has a database PCLS2018

I need to transfer data on a daily basis from Machine A database to Machine B database.

I tried to use an open query but failed. Then I tried to use linked server but could not create a linked server.

I expect after running the query the data on both databases deployed on different machines having different ip's will be same.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZ3jL.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vY42j.png)

Answer (score 0):

Linked server is a best solution to use distributed transaction and cross database\Instance call. Can you please share the details, why you are not able to create Linked Server?

Comment: Actually i dont know what should be write in the General Tab and Security Tab while creating the Linked server.

Comment: this Article can you better understating over Linked Server beginner.

https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-create-and-configure-a-linked-server-in-sql-server-management-studio/